# React Router ID dynamic routes with JSON data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

i'm totally beginner in react.
I tried to improve my skill day after day.
Today im stuck on problem, i want to create dynamic route with JSON characters (here dragon ball z)
My routes are correct but i want to show biography on only clicked characters like "i click on goku show goku bio"
**I want to make it without REACT HOOKS (dont useLocation, useParams ect..).**
At moment i'm totally stuck

Can you help me ? how can i do?

Thanks for help :)

here is the blitzstack of my project:

[REACT ROUTER DBZ EXERCICE - WITHOUT HOOKS](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uqbvn3?file=src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you are using `react-router-dom` and then not really use it for what it was designed for. You are working with function components, so as far as I can tell, any solution will require a React hook. Whether you just use the `useParams` hook to get the `id` to filter by, or if you declare an `id` state in the parent with `useState`, or create a React context and use both `useState` and `useContext`, or use Redux and `useDispatch` and `useSelector`. Do you see where this is headed?

I suggest just using the `useParams` hook as it's the most trivial to implement.

1. Fix the character bio route so the `id` route match param is easier to read and consume.

   ```
   <Route path="/CharBio/:id" element={<CharBio />} />
   ```

   With `path="/CharBio:id"` the link would inject a leading `:` character into the id with `` to={`/CharBio${element.id}`} ``, i.e. instead of `"goku"` the `id` param would be `":goku"`, and this doesn't work easily for filtering.
2. Fix the link in `Perso` so it's linking to a `"/CharBio/:id"` path.

   ```
   <Link to={`/CharBio/${element.id}`}>
     <h1>{element.id}</h1>
   </Link>
   ```
3. Use the `useParams` hook in the `CharBio` component and filter the `API` data by `id`.

   ```
   export default function CharBio() {
     const { id } = useParams();
     const element = API.find(el => el.id === id);
     return element ? <p>{element.bio}</p> : null;
   }
   ```